# HostIP.info get_json not calling jQuery ajax callback

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I'm just trying to get a user's IP address via jQuery/JSONP and had success with other services but I cannot determine why the callback is not called when using hostip.info's [JSON API](http://www.hostip.info/use.html)

Firebug and Fiddler both show the JSON response data I am expecting but success is never called and the error is a parse error so I must be missing something.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be great.  Thanks in advance.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wdqeV/1/)

Simple code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
        alert(json.ip);
    },
    error: function (request, type, status)
    {
       alert('[request: ' + request.statusText + '] [type: ' + type + '] [status: ' + status + ']');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service is json not jsonp, change `dataType` to `json`, see http://jsfiddle.net/wdqeV/3/

Comment: I had that before but running locally in Visual Studio I was getting a transport error so I switched to use JSONP.  That is another issue all together I guess.  Thanks.